# Draw network graph and get the coordinates of each node

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I would like to draw an undirected graph by specifying the nodes and the edges among them. This is currently done by, for example:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 1}]
```

In addition, I would like to lay out the graph within a specified region of x-y coordinate system. Imagine this specified region as the 'canvas' in which the above circle is drawn. For instance, such a canvas can be specified by four points such as `(0, 0), (100, 0), (100, 100), (0, 100)`.

Lastly, I would like to get the coordinates for each of the nodes of the graph drawn within the specified 'canvas'.

What is the right workflow in Mathematica to accomplish each of the steps above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess something like this:

```
net = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 1}; gp = GraphPlot[net];
pts = First[Cases[gp, GraphicsComplex[pts_, others___] :> pts, ∞]];

{xb, yb} = Composition[Through, {Min, Max}] /@ Transpose[pts];
Show[gp /. 
     GraphicsComplex[pts_, others___] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[MapThread[Rescale, {#, {xb, yb}, {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}}] & /@ pts,
                     others],
     Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True]
```

[image: rescaled graph]

Alternatively, one could have done

```
GraphPlot[net, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> True, 
          VertexCoordinateRules -> MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, 
            MapThread[Rescale, {#, {xb, yb}, {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}}] & /@ pts]]
```

The key is in extracting the coordinates from the handy structure provided by `GraphicsComplex[]`, and then applying the function `Rescale[]` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A related question, is it possible to tweak the layout of the graph within the specified region? For example, how do I rotate the graph by some degree clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Comment: Sure, you could do something like `Composition[RotationTransform[π/4], MapThread[Rescale, {#, {xb, yb}, {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}}] &] /@ pts` to rotate by 45 degrees anticlockwise, for instance...

Answer (score 4):

Build a graph and see what are the current coordinates:

```
g = CycleGraph[8, Axes -> True, GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork"]
```

[image]

Get coordinates via `GraphEmbedding`, then `Rescale` and verify:

```
SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> 100 Rescale[GraphEmbedding[g]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is neat. I can then get the transformed coordinates via `GraphEmbedding[
 SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> 100 Rescale[GraphEmbedding[g]]]]`. Thanks!

Comment: @skyork It is easier - the transformed coordinates are just: `100 Rescale[GraphEmbedding[g]]`

Comment: Great to know! Just starting to pick up Mathematica... Thanks for the help!

Comment: a quick follow-up question, what is the neatest way to generalize your approach to re-scale the graph to any given region? e.g. re-position the above circle at the center of the region defined by points `(0, 0), (0, 100), (150, 100), (0, 150)`.

Comment: @skyork `GraphEmbedding[g]` is just a set of points. Split them on separate X and Y coordinates, re-scale, and combine back.

Comment: that's right. I did it by extracting X and Y coordinates using `xcs=Rescale[GraphEmbedding[g]][[All,1]], ycs=Rescale[GraphEmbedding[g]][[All,2]]`, and then I can translate them to my desire. I combine them using `coords=Transpose[{xcs, ycs}]`, and display them using `SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> coords]`. If there is a better way, please let me know. Much appreciated!

Comment: `SetProperty` does not seem to be working with [`MorphologicalGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MorphologicalGraph.html).